# present progressive vs present simple

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

1.If your dog is wagging its tail when they're playing with another dog, that's a sign of a happy dog.

2.If a dog is wagging its tail when encountering an unfamiliar child, it is safe for the child to pet the dog.

If we replace in both sentences "wagging" with "wag" and also *they're playing* and *encountering* with "they play" and "it encounters", respectively, do we get the same meaning and equally natural sentences? For now I'll assume they do.

But what if we say
1.1. If your dog wags its tail when they're playing with another dog, that's a sign of a happy dog.
or
1.2. If your dog is wagging its tail when they they play with another dog, that's a sign of a happy dog.
I feel that this can be quite freely switched around.

It is also the case for the 2nd sentence?

Also, it is true that Americans tend to go for the present progressive constructions particularly often when the present simple fits the context, like in the sentences above? That's my impression watching a lot of American movies. But maybe I have in mind different contexts that I can't quite recall now.

Comment: Personally, I'm not keen on "singular they" for dogs, but if you're gonna use it, at least be consistent. It looks really bad to use both ***it*** and ***they*** in the same sentence: *If your dog wags **its** tail when **they're** playing...* is just awful. And I find it bogglingly unlikely that "Americans tend to go for the present progressive constructions" rather than Simple Present.

Comment: Yes, you can equally well switch tenses in Sentence 2.